# Derivation of the Ricci tensor from the Riemann tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, definition, curvature

We would like to obtain the Ricci tensor from the Riemann tensor.
In most books are contracted the first index with the third one, the second index with the fourth one. Following the same convention, I have obtained these identities. $$g^{ia}g^{lm}{R^k}_{lam}=g^{ia}{R^k}_a=R^{ik}$$ $$g^{im}g^{la}{R^k}_{lam}=-g^{im}g^{la}{R^k}_{lma}=-g^{im}{R^k}_m=-R^{ik}$$ Are they correct?

Comment: It depends on the convention you're using for the indices of the Riemann tensor, so I'd suggest to make them explicit. Also, observe that in order to obtain the covariant Ricci tensor $R_{\mu\nu}$ from the Riemann tensor you don't need the metric (you can just contract its upper index with one of the derivative indices, again depending on conventions). Then if you need the contravariant Ricci tensor $R^{\mu\nu}$ you can just raise the indices. Here you'll find all the info you need: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry .

Comment: I am following Landau Lifshitz. $R_{ik}={R^l}_{ilk}$ convention. What would be the contraction rule for this convention? In some books contracted the first and fourth indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventions change from author to author both with respect to the indices of the Riemann tensor and the definition of the Ricci tensor. I assume that $R^{i}_{\ jkl}=dx^{i}\left(R(\partial_{k},\partial_{l})\partial_{j}\right)$, where $R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_{X}\nabla_{Y}Z-\nabla_{Y}\nabla_{X}Z-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$, and $R_{ij}=R^{k}_{\ ikj}$, as per your comment.

Then

$$
R^{ji}=R^{ij}=g^{ik}g^{jl}R_{kl}=g^{ik}g^{jl}R^{m}_{\ kml}=g^{ik}g^{jl}g^{mn}R_{mknl}=g^{ik}g^{jl}g^{mn}R_{kmln}=g^{jl}g^{mn}R^{i}_{\ mln}
$$

where I have used $R_{ijkl}=R_{jilk}$ in the penultimate step. This is precisely your first formula, which is therefore correct. The second one is identical to the first one and follows from  $R^{i}_{\ jkl}=-R^{i}_{\ jlk}$. The intermediate equalities are also correct in a much more obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the link you gave. You contract the first and third indices, using $$R_{ik} = {R^l}_{ilk}$$
If you want to raise the indices, do so afterwards. Riemann is antisymmetric in the third and fourth indices, so 
$$R_{ik} = -{R^l}_{ikl}$$
and some books may use a different sign convention. Riemann is also antisymmetric in the first two indices,
$$R_{iklm}= - R_{kilm}  $$
so it is also possible to form Ricci by contracting with second and third, or with second and fourth.

Answer (score 0):

We know that  $R_{irs}^k$ is the Riemann tensor, if you contract $k$ and $r$ we'll have:

$$R_{is}=R_{iks}^k=\partial_k \Gamma_{is}^k-\partial_s \Gamma_{ik}^k+\Gamma_{is}^l \Gamma_{kl}^k -\Gamma_{ik}^l\Gamma_{sl}^k$$
$R_{is}$ is the Ricci tensor.
$$R_j^i=g^{ik}R_{kj}$$
The proprieties of symmetric of Riemann tensor can be applied, Ricci tensor is symmetric, with a simple contraction in $k$ and $r$ indices in the  $R_{irs}^k$ tensor 
$$R_{is}=R_{iks}^k=g^{kj}R_{ijks}=g^{kj}R_{ksij}$$
Note that :

$$R_{ijrs}=-R_{ijsr}  $$
Thus:
$$R_{is}=g^{kj}R_{ksij}=g^{kj}R_{ijks}=R_{ski}^k=R_{si}$$ 
And here is we conclude from the Riemann tensor the Ricci's one and its symmetric property.

Good luck !

Comment: In the fourth equation, there is no minus sign.

Comment: Double shuffling $1 \leftrightarrow 2$, $3 \leftrightarrow 4$ cancels the minus sign. By virtue of each shuffle is antisymmetric

Comment: No according to Riemann curvature tensor we have
$$R_{ijrs}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{ri}g_{sj}+\partial_{sj} g_{ir}-\partial_{rj}g_{is}-\partial_{si}g_{rj})$$
Permuting  $i$ and $j$:
$$R{jirs}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_{rj}g_{si}+\partial_{si}g_{jr}-\partial_{ri}g_{js}-\partial_{sj}g{ri})=-R_{ijrs}$$

Comment: Read @CharlesFrancis answer Riemann is antisymmetric in the first two indices

Comment: Look, you are shuffling the third and fourth indices.

Comment: sorry that was by a mistake thanks for paying attention to my answer !!

Comment: you are welcome!